# Why doesn't my hidden element appear as expected?

Tags: html, jquery

i have many article div and hidden article div, i want when click in more show hidden article but not work my code.

```
<div class="Abstract">I Have a hidden box in my HTML<div style="display:hidden;" class="hiddenAbstract" id=' + "hiddenAbstract" + i + '> Why not show the hidden box?</div><span class="BtnMoreAbstract"  id=' + "moreAbstract" + i + '>more</span></div>




<script>
$("#moreAbstract" + i).click(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == "more") {

            $("#hiddenAbstract" + i).css("display", "inline");

            $(this).text("less");
        }
        else {

            $("#hiddenAbstract" + i).css("display", "none");
            $(this).text("more");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You haven't quite provided enough code to be sure and reproduce your issue. I made a demo with a couple of assumptions, and the code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/tobfa6k8/ . So maybe compare your version to that, perhaps you have some differences.

Answer (score 0):

I solved your issue, I presume you are not generating correctly the div and span object through javascript.

Assuming you are creating the objects via JS, I presume you are not correcting using the " and ' in order to create the ID.

checks this fiddle with your code working: https://jsfiddle.net/g8jec4vr/13/

I used this sample with your code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    $('body').append('<div style="display:hidden;" class="hiddenAbstract" id="hiddenAbstract' + i + '"> Why not show the hidden box?</div><span class="BtnMoreAbstract"  id="moreAbstract' + i + '">more</span></div>');

}


for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    $("#moreAbstract" + i).on( "click", function() {

    alert('You clicked ' + i);
      if ($(this).text() == "more") {

        $("#hiddenAbstract" + i).css("display", "inline");

        $(this).text("less");
      } else {

        $("#hiddenAbstract" + i).css("display", "none");
        $(this).text("more");
      }
    });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you are using #hiddenAbstract as a DIV ID, but in your html code is a class, you must use .hiddenAbstract

Comment: `id=' + "hiddenAbstract" + i + '` in the HTML

Comment: saw recently.. sorry.  What returns "this" on the console if you add a breakpoint?

Comment: this return  #moreAbstract" + i 
and i write this code in jquery code not in html

Comment: @neda can you show us all your code then because currently I can get this code is working as is.